# Fatal error: Class 'Modelmyaccount' not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, netbeans, e-commerce, xampp

I am creating an e-commerce website using PHP and loaded up via XAMPP. However i encountered the following error: Fatal error: Class 'Modelmyaccount' not found

I have tried debugging using NetBeans with XDebug enabled, an encountered the the following call stack.

```
Call Stack

 1. {main}( ) ..\index.php:0
 2. require_once( 'E:\xampp\htdocs\promotion\system\codeigniter\CodeIgniter.php' ) ..\index.php:117
 3. myshop->__construct( ) ..\CodeIgniter.php:201
 4. CI_Loader->model( ???, ???, ??? ) ..\myshop.php:7
```

I have verified that the class do exist, however it just doesn't seem to recognize it.

Below highlighted in bold is the part where it just cannot find the class name to store into $name

```
if ( ! class_exists('Model'))
    {
        load_class('Model', FALSE);
    }

    **require_once(APPPATH.'models/'.$path.$model.EXT);**

    $model = ucfirst($model);

    $CI->$name = new $model();
    $CI->$name->_assign_libraries();

    $this->_ci_models[] = $name;    
}
```

Please also see the 'modelmyaccount' and 'Model' class for reference below:

```
<?
class modelmyaccount extends Model{

    protected   $table_name = 'consumer_master';


    function __construct()
    {
        parent::Model();

        $this->table_country_master     = 'country_master';
        //$this->table_country_detail   = 'country_detail';
        $this->table_state_master       = 'state_master';
        //$this->table_state_detail         = 'state_detail';
    }

    function checkEmail()
    {

      $fetch_user = "SELECT count(*) AS CNT FROM ".$this->table_name." 
                     WHERE email     = '".addslashes($_POST['email'])."'
                    ";
      $fetch_result=$this->db->query($fetch_user);      

      if($fetch_result->num_rows() > 0) {
           $row=$fetch_result->row_array();
           if($row['CNT'] == 0) {
              return true;
           }else {
              return false;
          }
      }
   }

   function updateMember($member_id)
   {

    $dt = explode("-",addslashes($_POST['birth_date']));
    $birth_date = $dt[2]."-".$dt[0]."-".$dt[1];

    $saveSql = "UPDATE ".$this->table_name." 
                SET first_name      =   '".addslashes($_POST['first_name'])."',
                    last_name       =   '".addslashes($_POST['last_name'])."',
                    streetname          =   '".addslashes($_POST['address1'])."',   
                    dob     =   '".$birth_date."',
                    interest            =   '".addslashes($_POST['interest'])."',
                    country         =   '".addslashes($_POST['country'])."',
                    state           =   '".addslashes($_POST['state'])."',
                    city            =   '".addslashes($_POST['city'])."',
                    postal              =   '".addslashes($_POST['zip'])."',



                    edit_date   =   NOW()
                WHERE consumer_id = '".$member_id."'
                ";              
     //echo $saveSql;
     //exit;
      $saveResult = $this->db->query($saveSql);

      return true;  

   }

   /*function delMyFav($member_id, $topic_type)
   {
        $sql_del = "DELETE FROM favourite_master 
                    WHERE   member_id='".$member_id."' 
                    AND     topic_type='".$topic_type."'";
        $result = $this->db->query($sql_del);
   }*/

   function checkConfirmation($emailId)
   {
     $sql = "SELECT status FROM ".$this->table_name." 
             WHERE   email ='".base64_decode($emailId)."'";
     $res = $this->db->query($sql);
     if($res->num_rows() > 0) {
       $row = $res->row_array();
       if($row['status']=='A') 
            return false;
       else 
            return true;
     }
   }

   function confirmMember($emailId)
   {
     $confirmSql = "UPDATE ".$this->table_name. "
                    SET status = 'A' 
                    WHERE email ='".base64_decode($emailId)."'";

     $confirmResult = $this->db->query($confirmSql);

     if($confirmResult) {
       return true;
     }   
   }

   function getCountry()
   {
        $sql = " SELECT  CM.*
                 FROM  " .$this->table_country_master. " AS CM               
                 WHERE CM.is_active ='Y'";
        $recordSet = $this->db->query($sql);

        if($recordSet) {
            if($recordSet->num_rows() > 0) {
                foreach($recordSet->result_array() as $key =>$val) {
                    $rs[]=$val;
                }
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        return $rs ;
   }

   function getMemberById($member_id)
   {

       $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$this->table_name." WHERE consumer_id = '".$member_id."'";
       $recordset = $this->db->query($sql);

       if($recordset->num_rows() > 0){
           foreach($recordset->result_array() as $key=>$val){
               $rs[] = $val;
           }
       }else{
            return false;   
       }

       return $rs;
   }

   function validateOldPassword($id)
    {   

        $this->old_pwd   = $this->input->request('old_pwd','');

        $sql = " SELECT count(*) AS CNT 
                 FROM   ".$this->table_name." 
                 WHERE  consumer_id ='".$id."' 
                 AND    password ='".$this->old_pwd."'
               ";       
        $rs  = $this->db->query($sql);

        if($rs) {
            if($rs->num_rows() > 0) { 
                $row = $rs->row_array();
                if($row['CNT'] > 0) {
                  return true;
                } else {
                 return false;
                }
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {            
            return false;
        }
    }

    /*
    function valideNewPassword
    This function to check the New Password and Confirm New Password will be same or not
    if both are the same then return true else return false
    */
    function validateNewPassword() 
    {
        $this->new_pwd        = $this->input->request('new_pwd','');
        $this->conf_new_pwd     = $this->input->request('con_pwd','');

        if($this->new_pwd!='' && $this->conf_new_pwd!='') {
            if($this->new_pwd===$this->conf_new_pwd) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }

    function updatePassword($id)
    {
        $this->new_pwd   = $this->input->request('new_pwd','');


        $sql = " UPDATE ".$this->table_name." 
                 SET    password = '".$this->new_pwd."' 
                 WHERE  consumer_id ='".$id."'
               ";

        $rs  = $this->db->query($sql);

        if($rs) {
            return true;
        } else {            
            return false;
        }
    }

    function newsletterSubscription($subscriberEmail)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT subscriber_email 
                FROM newsletter_subscriber
                WHERE subscriber_email = '".$subscriberEmail."'
                AND is_active = 'Y' 
                ";
        //echo $sql;
        $rs = $this->db->query($sql);
        if($rs){
            if($rs->num_rows() > 0){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }       
        }
    }

    function subscribeNewsletter($subscriberEmail)
    {
        $sql = "
                INSERT INTO newsletter_subscriber
                SET 
                    subscriber_email = '".$subscriberEmail."',
                    is_active = 'Y',
                    db_add_date = NOW(),
                    db_edit_date = NOW()            
               ";
        //echo $sql;       
        $rs = $this->db->query($sql);
        if($rs){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }   
    function unSubscribeNewsletter($subscriberEmail)
    {   
        $sql = "
                DELETE FROM newsletter_subscriber
                WHERE 
                    subscriber_email = '".$subscriberEmail."'               
               ";
        $rs = $this->db->query($sql);
        if($rs){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }          

    }

}
?>
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/**
 * CodeIgniter
 *
 * An open source application development framework for PHP 4.3.2 or newer
 *
 * @package     CodeIgniter
 * @author      ExpressionEngine Dev Team
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2008 - 2009, EllisLab, Inc.
 * @license     http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/license.html
 * @link        http://codeigniter.com
 * @since       Version 1.0
 * @filesource
 */

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * CodeIgniter Model Class
 *
 * @package     CodeIgniter
 * @subpackage  Libraries
 * @category    Libraries
 * @author      ExpressionEngine Dev Team
 * @link        http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html
 */
class Model {

    var $_parent_name = '';

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @access public
     */
    function Model()
    {
        // If the magic __get() or __set() methods are used in a Model references can't be used.
        $this->_assign_libraries( (method_exists($this, '__get') OR method_exists($this, '__set')) ? FALSE : TRUE );

        // We don't want to assign the model object to itself when using the
        // assign_libraries function below so we'll grab the name of the model parent
        $this->_parent_name = ucfirst(get_class($this));

        log_message('debug', "Model Class Initialized");
    }

    /**
     * Assign Libraries
     *
     * Creates local references to all currently instantiated objects
     * so that any syntax that can be legally used in a controller
     * can be used within models.  
     *
     * @access private
     */ 
    function _assign_libraries($use_reference = TRUE)
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();              
        foreach (array_keys(get_object_vars($CI)) as $key)
        {
            if ( ! isset($this->$key) AND $key != $this->_parent_name)
            {           
                // In some cases using references can cause
                // problems so we'll conditionally use them
                if ($use_reference == TRUE)
                {
                    $this->$key = NULL; // Needed to prevent reference errors with some configurations
                    $this->$key =& $CI->$key;
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->$key = $CI->$key;
                }
            }
        }       
    }

}
// END Model Class

/* End of file Model.php */
/* Location: ./system/libraries/Model.php */
```

Comment: If you're on a Unix system be careful of name cases

Comment: i am on a Windows 7 system. Other classes which are in the same folder able to go through. However certain classes just wont do. This is one of the classes that was 'ModelMyAccount', however I have changed it to 'modelmyaccount' instead. But still didnt work. Is there some place that I might missed out?

Comment: Are you saying that other models are being loaded fine? Did yo check for typos?

Comment: 1.  how are you instantiating the class and 2.  How is your class spelled in the instantiation ie. Class ModelMyAccount.....?

Comment: I have used Notepad++ to open up all .php files, find 'ModelMyAccount' and replaced it with 'modelmyaccount'. The .php file stored at my application directory is also having the name modelmyaccount.php

Comment: Just to add on I am using CodeIgniter for the framework. Not too sure if there is some compatibilaty issue.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:
[CodeIgniter User Guide - Models](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html)

If you look up "Anatomy of a Model", you will see that you need to correct your name conventions for CodeIgniter to find your models properly. You class name **must** have its first letter capitalized like so:

```
class Modelmyaccount extends Model {
```

Also, if you want to follow the CodeIgniter naming conventions properly; you should name your file `my_account_model.php`. Also, change the class name accordingly like so:

```
class My_account_model extends Model{
```

Furthermore, what version of CodeIgniter are you using? your models should extend `CI_Model` or if your using your own extension to the model class, it should be `MY_Model` unless you set a different prefix in your `config.php` file.

So your model class declaration should look like this if your using version 2.1.3:

```
class My_account_model extends CI_Model {
```

Replace `CI_` with which prefix your using.